# Backing files up with Dropbox and Google Drive simultaneously

Tags: backup, mirroring, cloud-storage

I know there are potentially ways to do this by putting your dropbox folders within your Google Drive folder, but it makes me a bit nervous. I have plenty of room on my hard drive, so figured maybe the best solution would be to just have a secondary directory tree for Google Drive that would "mirror" most of the folders from my Dropbox folder tree.  However, I don't want to have to manually manage every time I make changes.  I'm wondering if there is an application that would either immediately or on a schedule (say every night at 3am), make the changes in the Google Drive folder that had just been made in the Dropbox one?  I'm sure there are probably many out there that do this, but I guess I'm looking for the most reliable, well-known ones, preferably free, or at least under $20 if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) allows you to schedule folder syncing. Here is a [guide to set up scheduled syncing in SyncToy](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25046/schedule-synctoy-to-run-automatically-with-task-scheduler-in-windows-7/).